# How to copy objects of Different classes which has same attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, object, inheritance, model

Good day friends!

I have 2 model classes say **Page** and **PageHistory**. both contains same attributes. Here whenever I edit a **Page** object, I need to update **PageHistory** object with same property values.

I tried something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit(Page page, FormCollection frm)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    page.IsPublished = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["BtnPublish"]);
                    _db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    //Add updated page in hitory, if something is modified
                    PageHistory ph=new PageHistory();
                    ph.ID=page.ID
                    // likewise all attributes.....
                    // after all values are assigned, save a History object
                    ph.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Subpages", new { id = page.ParentId });
                }
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator (http://support.mysite.com).");
            }
            return View(page);
        }
```

It is working, But this is not so optimized, is there any alternatives available to copy objects? and one more question is, Is it possible to **Inherit** the **PageHistory** class from **Page** class, because both contains same attributes? which one is the best approach?

Comment: By "attributes", you mean "properties" yes?

Comment: And why u need two models which has the very same properties? I mean, is it unavoidable in your project?

Comment: Ok, this can be overkill (and probably is) but, have you looked at Automapper? http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: @VladislavQulin I agree. I think the OP might to try a shallow copy for his purpose but is not aware of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would recommend you to use the same model for same data presentation.
2. I would recommend you to create inherit class PageHistory. It will allow you to cast Page to PageHistory like:

   ```
   (PageHistory) page;
   ```
3. I would recommend you to incapsulate that PageHistory props copying behind interface like:

   ```
   public interface IPageHistoryBuilder
   {
       PageHistory Build(Page page);
   }

   public class PageHistoryBuilder : IPageHistoryBuilder
   {
       public PageHistory Build(Page page)
       {
           return new PageHistory
           {
               // copy ALL the props here
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Your code will look like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    page.IsPublished = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm["BtnPublish"]);
    _db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();

    var ph = pageHistoryBuilder.Build(page);
    ph.SaveChanges();
// and so long
}
```

And don't forget about declaring the builder in controller constructor:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
     private readonly IPageHistoryBuilder pageHistoryBuilder;
     public YourController(IPageHistoryBuilder pageHistoryBuilder)
     {
         this.pageHistoryBuilder = pageHistoryBuilder;
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, looks neat, If I go through last one (3rd one) how my Update method looks like?

Comment: @MVC3Seeker, i've made an update to the answer, but you'll probably want to know about IoC-container.